# Using Taylor polynomials to approximate a function

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I am asked the following: Using the Taylor polynomial, find $\int_0^{0.2} e^{x^2}dx$ with the error $<10^{-3}$

My attempt:

First, I will compute $\int_0^{0.2} e^{x^2}dx$ using calculus:

$\int_0^{0.2} e^{x^2}dx=1/2[e^{x^2}]_0 ^{0.2} = \dfrac{1}{2} (e^{1/25-1})= 0.02040538709$

Now let's compute $\int_0^{0.2} e^{x^2}dx$ numerically using the Taylor expansion of $e^{x^2}$

$e^{x^2} = \Sigma_{n=o} ^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n}}{n!}$

Now my question is do I just integrate the first term, then the sum of the first two terms etc... until I get and error $ < 10^{-3}$?

Comment: Sorry, but $e^{x^2}$ is a lot harder to integrate than that (no closed form exists for the integral).

Comment: Your  first integral is false: $\int\mathrm e^{x^2}\,\mathrm d x$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. You have to find an estimate for the error term when you expand Taylor's formula at order $n$ and deduce a value of $n$ which ensures this error is less than $10^{-3}$.

Comment: The way I reasonned was as follow: $(1/2 e^{x^2})' = (1/2 e^{2x})' = e^{2x} = e^{x^2}$. so I used $(1/2 e^{x^2})$ as an antiderivative and simply used the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @lulu sorry I wasn't stating anything, just want to show my reasonning. Could you explain why the reasonning is wrong?

Comment: This is because it is $e^{(x^2)}$, so the exponent rule $(a^b)^c=(a^c)^b$ doesn't apply.

Comment: $e^{x^2}$ means $e^{(x^2)}$.  Thus, with $x=3$ we get $e^9$. On the other hand,  $e^{2x}$ is a different function.  At $x=3$ that one evaluates to $e^6$.

Answer (score 0):

Your Taylor series would be
$$\int e^{x^2} dx = x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{10} + \frac{x^7}{42} + \frac{x^9}{216} + \frac{x^{11}}{1320}$$
At $x=0.2$, the $x^5$ term is already way smaller than $10^{-3}$, at $0.000032$, $x^7$ term is at $0.000000304761905$, and the terms just keep on getting smaller. In this case, this error will not exceed $10^{-3}$, and the  so all we need is
$$0.2 + \frac{0.2^3}{3} \approx0.2026666 \approx 0.203$$

Comment: It is not generally true that the error in truncating a positive series is bounded by the first omitted term.  You need to use Taylor's Theorem with Remainder.